# Passing in environment variables into docker file that is build via a compose yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am calling a docker file thru my docker compose file by running command docker-compose build. I have my environment variables defined in a .env file. When I do the build, in my docker file, everything works except this line

```
RUN git config --global user.email ${USER_NAME}
```

It fails with the message

```
←[31mERROR←[0m: Service 'git' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c git confi
g --global user.email ${USER_NAME}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

However if I echo ${USER_NAME} during container load (docker-compose up) it is able to print out that variable correctly.

```
ENTRYPOINT  echo ${USER_NAME}//this works
```

**What is the right way to pass in an environment variable in a run command in the docker file?**

Update: Here is a stripped down version of the files

yaml file

```
version: '2'
services:
    git:
        build:
          context: ./git
          args:
            - USER_NAME
        env_file:
         - ./common.env
```

Env file

```
USER_NAME="My test user"
```

Docker file:

```
FROM xxx

ARG USER_NAME 

RUN git config --global user.name ${USER_NAME} 
ENTRYPOINT git config --list
```

Commands
Build:

```
docker-compose build git
```

Run:

```
docker-compose up git
```

The build fails with the error

```
RUN git config --global user.name ${USER_NAME}
 ---> Running in 7b67ddeae989
←[31mERROR←[0m: Service 'git' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c git config --global user.name ${USER_NAME}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Including a more complete example of your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile would make it easier to assist.

Comment: Your `git` command is failing, from the limited error message provided, it's not possible to say why (is git installed?). Try running it directly inside an a container, and make sure it's not prompting for input or giving a bad exit code. Your `.env` file contents may also be helpful to debug this.

Comment: added .env contents. If I hardcode the username it works. Reading the environment directly at runtime also works.

Comment: Try quoting your arg: `RUN git config --global user.name "${USER_NAME}"`

Answer (score 3):

The .env applies to the docker-compose.yml. Assuming you are building a Dockerfile from within your compose (e.g. `docker-compose build`), then you can pass an `ARG` from compose into the build to provide this variable for build `RUN`:

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
build:
  args:
    USER_NAME: ${USER_NAME}
```

Dockerfile:

```
...
ARG USER_NAME=developer747
RUN git config --global user.email ${USER_NAME}
```

---

Here's an example of this in my lab:

```
$ cat docker-compose.build-arg.yml
version: '2'

services:
  build-test:
    build:
      args:
        USER_NAME: ${USER_NAME}
      context: .
      dockerfile: df.build-arg
    image: test-build-args

$ cat .env
ENV=default
USER_NAME=test2

$ cat df.build-arg
FROM busybox

ARG USER_NAME=default
RUN adduser --disabled-password ${USER_NAME}
CMD tail -f /dev/null

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.build-arg.yml up --build -d
Building build-test
Step 1 : FROM busybox
 ---> 2b8fd9751c4c
Step 2 : ARG USER_NAME=default
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9be5b562c784
Step 3 : RUN adduser --disabled-password ${USER_NAME}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bcbaf683e3cf
Step 4 : CMD tail -f /dev/null
 ---> Running in 66908e4f7a0c
 ---> 06b9774253c2
Removing intermediate container 66908e4f7a0c
Successfully built 06b9774253c2
Recreating test_build-test_1

$ docker exec -it test_build-test_1 /bin/sh
/ # tail /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/false
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/false
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/false
sync:x:4:100:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/spool/mail:/bin/false
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/false
operator:x:37:37:Operator:/var:/bin/false
nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/home:/bin/false
test2:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/test2:/bin/sh
/ # exit
```

Comment: I don't want the value developer747 hardcoded in the docker file. It should come from the .env file.

Comment: That's not hard coded in there, the value in the Dockerfile is a default value if you fail to pass an arg during the docker build. Pick a sensible default value that makes sense for your image.

Comment: I tried it out. It picked the value developer747. It did not pick what was in the .env file. Apparently there are different ways to fetch environment variables during build time and run time. I will play around with it a little more.

Comment: How are you building your images? Again, a more complete example of your scenario would help.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work yet. But I really appreciate all the effort you have been putting in to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ENV USER_NAME developer747
RUN git config --global user.email ${USER_NAME}
```

refer: [Environment replacement¶](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/environment-replacement)

Comment: But I want it to read this environment from a .env file. Which works if I am reading it on Entrypoint. In the example you posted, it is being hard coded in the docker file and is not being read from a file.