# How to deal with extensive .gitconfig with multiple identities and Visual Studio Code devcontainers?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

It seems like Visual Studio Code and it's dev containers copy the `.gitconfig` upon creation. As I have to manage different identities I've quite an extensive `.gitconfig`, which load other configuration files conditionally. For example:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Workspace/github.com/"]
    path = .gitconfig-github.com
```

Of course Visual Studio Code doesn't copy them and even if it wouldn't work as the conditional doesn't apply because it will detect the wrong directory.

Anyhow, is it somehow possible to run `git config --get user.name` and `git config --get user.email` outside of the container within the working directory and set it to the devcontainer upon creation?

---

#### Update

The problem is it's not possible to retrieve the return values from commands within a `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile` to hand it over to the container right?

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        VARIANT: 14
        GIT_USERNAME: ${git config --get user.name}
        GIT_USERMAIL: ${git config --get user.email}
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
    command: sleep infinity
```

Something like this wouldn't work. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated by:

- [commit 1641597](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/commit/164159789faf76fdae6571ca205146352e10a551) (Update `docker-compose.yml` files to mount `.gitconfig`)
- [commit 3ad0b8b](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/commit/3ad0b8bad637e5694fc736d6aa8293f5dec0addd) (Remove `.gitconfig` mount now that its copied)

You would need to modify/patch the `container-templates/docker-compose/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml` and others `containers/xxx/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml` in order to add any instruction automatically executed by VSCode whencreating a new container.

That path would include a way to select the right config/identity to use in order to modify the mounted `.gitconfig` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering me. The idea I've outlined is hard to make it work? Taking the the current `user.name` and `user.email` from the outside and pass it inside the container upon creation?

Comment: @Robin Yes, that would work, provided the docker-compose.yml are aware of those parameters.

Comment: How can I retrieve it from outside of the container? I've updated the question.

Comment: @Robin You would need to pass `user.name` as an argument in the `build` section of your `docker-compose.yml`, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963295/6309